# Cómo corregir error java.io.FileNotFoundException en PDF

Tags: java, archivo, netbeans-8.2

Hola actualmente estoy haciendo un programita en java (netbeans) y tengo un boton para imprimir un reporte ya tengo importada la libreria y todo ello pero me da un error y no logro solucionarlo. El problema que me da es este

> Error en PDF o ruta de imagen java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sebas\Desktop\JULIA TEREZA DE JESUS QUILLE FERNANDEZ.pdf (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 25 seconds)

```
Document documento = new Document();

    try {

        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/" + txt_nombre.getText().trim() + ".pdf"));

        com.itextpdf.text.Image header = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance("src/images/BannerPDF.jpg");
        header.scaleToFit(650, 1000);
        header.setAlignment(Chunk.ALIGN_CENTER);

        Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph();
        parrafo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
        parrafo.add("Información del cliente. \n \n");
        parrafo.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Tahoma", 14, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY));

        documento.open();
        documento.add(header);
        documento.add(parrafo);

        PdfPTable tablaCliente = new PdfPTable(8);
        tablaCliente.addCell("ID");
        tablaCliente.addCell("Nombre y apellido");
        tablaCliente.addCell("Cuenta Contrato");
        tablaCliente.addCell("Cédula");
        tablaCliente.addCell("Email");
        tablaCliente.addCell("Direccion");
        tablaCliente.addCell("Meses Pendientes");
        tablaCliente.addCell("Valor Vencido");

        try {
            Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(
                    "select * from clientes where id_cliente = '" + IDcliente_update + "'");

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                do {

                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(1));
                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(5));
                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(2));
                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(4));
                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(10));
                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(8));
                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(25));
                    tablaCliente.addCell(rs.getString(27));

                } while (rs.next());

                documento.add(tablaCliente);

            }

            Paragraph parrafo2 = new Paragraph();
            parrafo2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            parrafo2.add("\n \n Detalle de notificación. \n \n");
            parrafo2.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Tahoma", 14, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY));
```

Comment: Al ponerle trim(), ¿No estarías quitándole los espacios? Por lo que si tu pdf tiene espacios en su nombre, no lo va a encontrar

Comment: ¿En qué línea de código mandas a escribir el archivo? No la veo, ahí está el detalle.

Comment: perdon si suena a algo tonto pero... ya intentaste crear un archivo vacío primero en esa ruta y ver si con eso ya funciona?